# How can I separate a column into multiple columns based on values?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have searched on a lot of pages but I cannot find a solution to my problem except in reverse order. I have simplified what I do, but I have a query that comes looking for information in my data sheet. Here there are 3 columns, the date, the amount and the source.

[image: Data Screenshot]

I would like, with a query function, to be able to make different columns which counts the information of column C based on the values of its cells per month, like this

[image]

I'm okay with the start of the formula

```
=QUERY(A2:C,"select month(A)+1, sum(B), count(C) where A is not null group by month(A)+1")
```

But as soon as I try a little different things by putting 2 query together in an arrayformula, obviously the row count doesn't match as some minus are 0 for some sources.

Do you have a solution for what I'm trying to do? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX({
 QUERY({MONTH(A2:A), B2:C}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label Col1'month',sum(Col2)'amount'"), 
 QUERY({MONTH(A2:A), B2:C, C2:C}, 
 "select count(Col3) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 pivot Col4")})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

It's not possible in Google Query Language to have a single query statement that has one result grouped by one column and another result grouped by another.

The first two columns can be like this:

```
=QUERY(A2:C,"select month(A)+1, sum(B) where A is not null group by month(A)+1 label month(A)+1 'Month', sum(B) 'Amount'")
```

To create the column labels for the succeeding columns, use in the first row, in my example, I1:

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(C2:C))
```

Then from cell I2, enter this:

```
=COUNTIFS(arrayformula(month($A$2:$A)),$G2,$C$2:$C,I$1)
```

Then drag horizontally and vertically to apply to the entire table.

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer !
Yes I suspected that it was not possible but that there was maybe a way to get around this problem. I decided to use the player0 solution which is closer to my initial need.